# Laravel VerifyCsrfToken Exception not working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make a simple Ajax post using Laravel 5. I read that there is a issue with the Csrf Token matching and that i could put my uri into the VerifyCsrfToken expection to step around this. Did I mess something up in my code? How can I get this working? Here is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "event-carousel" class = "carousel slide">

                                                <div id = "event-news" class = "carousel-inner">
                                                    {{--*/ $isFirst = true; /*--}}
                                                    @foreach($events as $event)
                                                        <div class="item{{{ $isFirst ? ' active' : '' }}}">
                                                          <div class = "foto we">
                                                            <img src ="/assets/image/{{$event->photo}}" alt = "intexhange" class= "img-responsive">
                                                          </div>
                                                          <div class = "mask">
                                                                <h1>{{$event->title}}</h1>
                                                                <div class = "secinfo">
                                                                    <p>{{$event->teacher}}</p>
                                                                    <p>{{$event->location}}</p>
                                                                    <p>{{$event->published_at}}</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                              <div class = pitch>
                                                                <p class = "subhead-how">{{$event->description}}</p>
                                                                 {!!Form::open(array('url' => 'book')) !!}
                                                                      {!! Form::hidden('title', $event->title, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                                                      {!! Form::hidden('user_id', $myid, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                                                      <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                          <span href="#event-carousel" data-slide="prev"class = "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>{!!Form::button('Join Activity', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger jact'))!!}<span href="#event-carousel" data-slide="next" class = "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
                                                                  {!! Form::close() !!}
                                                              </div>
                                                          </div>
                                                    {{--*/ $isFirst = false; /*--}}
                                                    </div>
                                                    @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                           </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.jact').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();


   var title = $(this).find('input[title=title]').val();
   var user_id = $(this).find('input[user_id=user_id]').val();

   $.post('book', {title: title, user_id: user_id}, function(data){
       console.log(data);
   })
```

});

**Controller:**

```
 public function book()
{

    if(Request::ajax()){

        return Response::json(Input::all());

    }
}
```

**VerifyCsrfToken:**

```
  class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{

    protected $except = [
        'book/*'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the uri your ajax posts to? Try removing the CSRF token from your form, no point including it if your not using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$except` functionality uses the `Illuminate\Http\Request::is()` method. It loops through the `$except` array and tests the current request against each entry. If one matches, it will skip the verification.

From the code, it looks like you're posting to `book`, not a url under book. If you were to call `$request->is('book/*')`, it would return false, since you're not at a url under `book`.

If you would like to ignore `book`, and all of its descendants, you will want this:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
        'book',
        'book/*'
    ];
}
```